# Rectangular Region Detection in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV and I am seeking help in an algorithm in Python.

I am trying to identify the region in an image where most of the rectangular shapes appear. 
In particular, I have several images of equal size, with one single rectangle appearing in each image (all these images are stored in the [probability_image_array.npy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZMqwP8qFcS29Vy1Dj0mcrDck7JKTHIG/view?usp=sharing) file). I am summing all these images to obtain a single final image ([probabiliy_image.npy](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qR0P0pnoebekm04AmoKLMvUJowSFRspE)), also shown in the figure below.
My task is to find the most prominent rectanguar region in this final image, i.e. where visibly most of the rectangles are appearing. In the file Figure_1_expected output.png you have an example of the output I am expecting to obain.

Thanks for your help

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSUo3.png)

[Figure_1_expected output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs34C.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) the image, so that the most prominent rectangular region shows up as a binary mask. Followed by findContours and boundingRect you will get the expected output.